# MyFaces to Mojarra migration issue

Tags: jsf, migration, facelets, myfaces, mojarra

I'm migrating from MyFaces 1.2.6 to Mojarra 1.2.
My application also uses Facelets, Tomahawk and Richfaces.

Using MyFaces 1.2.6, it works without problems.
Using Mojarra 1.2, I got some problems.

It keeps printing this error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 141 at column 36: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Content of line 141:

```
<f:facet name="footer">
```

Does anyone know what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Given the error **xmlParseEntityRef**, I would check for stray [XML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-physical-struct) (look for ampersands - **&**).

Also check the values being emitted by any EL expressions (e.g. ${baz.mystring}). If MyFaces encoded the string "foo & bar" as **foo &amp; bar**, but the RI emitted it straight as **foo & bar**, then this might cause a problem.